# PrimeNG's styles are not being applied even if my order is correct in angular.json file. "styles.scss" is overriding it

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using Prime NG in my Angular Application and I have some styles of my own too. I have integrated the priority order of my styles in `angular.json` file in the `styles` array. Though I am using the correct order, my custom styles are being applied first and not the prime ng's style.

I have a `_reset-and-normalize.scss` file which gives `margin`, `padding` and `border` as `0`. This style is imported in my `styles.scss` file. Due to this, I'm not sure why, but my prime ng's styles are being overridden by my properties mentioned in `_reset-and-normalize.scss` even if the order is perfectly proper in `angular.json`.

angular.json

```
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/ff-cms",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.svg",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/lara-light-indigo/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/summernote/dist/summernote-lite.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/summernote/dist/summernote-lite.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "optimization": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "5mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "1mb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "preprod": {
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "optimization": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "5mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "1mb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.preprod.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "stage": {
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "optimization": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "5mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "1mb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.stage.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.local.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
```

styles.scss

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */

/* Fonts */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');

/* Helper CSS */
@import 'assets/css/_common.scss';
@import 'assets/css/_typography.scss';
@import 'assets/css/_grid.scss';
@import 'assets/css/_pattern.scss';
@import 'assets/css/_variables.scss';
@import 'assets/css/_reset-and-normalize.scss';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the import directly in your global style file, also install primeflex (CSS library used from PrimeNg):

Style.scss:

```
$gutter: 1rem; //for primeflex grid system

@import "primeng/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css";
@import "primeng/resources/primeng.min.css";
@import "primeflex/primeflex.scss";

/*
 Your global styles
*/
```

Then delete the import from angular.json's style array.

That worked for me

Comment: Hi @MartinAraujo! I did tried this too. Didn't work. Added it in `styles.scss` and also added it in `angular.json`, that didn't work. Then removed it from `angular.json`, that didn't work too. Not sure, what else to do. I have the same structure in a different project too. It's working fine there.

Comment: Did you import provideAnimations() from '@angular/platform-browser/animations' into `app.config.ts` file?